# Unit of measurement for entanglement between two particles?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Do any theoretical frameworks employ a unit of measurement to quantify the "strength" of the entanglement between two particles?

For example, when the particles are unentangled, the unit is 0, but strongly entangled particles have a high real value.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163) proposes, compares and contrasts several possible quantitative measures of entanglement.

Comment: It's important to be clear from the outset that no single measure can ever be sufficient. The reason is that the comparison "A is more entangled than B" (in the sense of "A can be transformed into B using local operations and classical communication") is a partial (i.e. not a total) order, so that the transformation is impossible in either direction. When that is the case, it is hard to compare the "strength" of entanglement between those two states.